# Sublime 2 how to overwrite the Emmet plugin keyboard shortcuts

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to "increase/decrease number by 1" feature introduced by Emmet plugin, and would like to have the default behavior - move line up/down by 1 line - back.

This is how the keyboard shortcut defined in `preference > package settings > Emmet > key bindings - default`:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+up"], 
    "args": {"action": "increment_number_by_1"}, 
    "command": "run_emmet_action", 
    "context": [{"key": "emmet_action_enabled.increment_number_by_1"}]
},
```

I added this in the `preference > package settings > Emmet > key bindings - user`:

```
{
    "keys": [""], 
    "args": {"action": "increment_number_by_1"},
    "command": "run_emmet_action", 
    "context": [{"key": "emmet_action_enabled.increment_number_by_1"} ] 
},
```

But this didn't overwrite the original Emmet setting. How should I disable this?

Comment: Could you just define the default behavior in user setting: `{ "keys": ["ctrl+up"], "command": "scroll_lines", "args": {"amount": 1.0 } }`? I don't think `"keys": [""]` can restore keyboard shortcut.

Comment: I just commented it out in default settings. Hope nothing overwrites the default settings in the future.

Comment: Stan - the default settings will be overwritten every time the package is updated. You should use @lhuang's way instead in your user setting.

Answer (score 9):

Navigate to `Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Settings – User`.

Add the following to the file and save it:

```
{
    "disabled_keymap_actions": "increment_number_by_1, decrement_number_by_1"
}
```

Comment: For the full list of available actions (and shortcuts) you can disable, see [the emmet-sublime repo](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions). You'll have to guess at the underscored name, e.g. "Reflect CSS Value" becomes "reflect_css_value" if you want your default Ctrl-Shift-R shortcut back.

Comment: This helped me with sublime's `ctrl+u` `soft_undo` not working. The action name is `update_image_size`